# How to get rid of horizontal scroling?

Tags: css, joomla-3.5

I wanted to make a background image being fully visible in all resolutions. It was suggested to me to use this code to achieve it:

```
body {background:none !important;}
.header-outer { background: #fff url(http://idevsky.com/images/1.jpg) no-repeat
center center;background-size: contain;width: 100vw;height: calc(100vw / 1.5);}
```

It does show the image the way I want, but there's an unwanted "side-effect" to it for some reason. Now I get a small horizontal scrolling. So my question is how to avoid it? Here's the site's URL:

http://idevsky.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to contain the background image or set the width. Simply set the height of the element to the viewport height and then make the background `cover` this area:

```
.header-outer {
    background: #fff url(http://idevsky.com/images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: If you meant to remove the old code in custom.css and embed yours, then after that the image is gone alogether, but the horizontal scrolling stayed, so I reverted the change.

Comment: Could you please apply my change again and let me know once done so I can inspect the source code again

Comment: Now after I removed my code and put back yours, the image is there and there's no horizontal scrolling, but the image is set too high, so you can't see even the head of the woman on the picture or her right hand.

Comment: That's what happens under MY resolution, which is 1366x768

Comment: Seems perfectly fine for me if I set my browser viewport to those dimensions. If you have your browser inspector open, then close it

Comment: FOR YOU... What's your resolution? 'cos I've checked my site on 1920x1200 and it DOES look Okay, but that doesn't help me, unfortunately... Nothing is open in my browser. I don't open it, 'cos I won't understand a thing anyways :-)

Comment: Like I said, I set my browser viewport to the dimensions (1366 x 768) you mentioned. See image: http://imgur.com/a/wIYQu

Comment: You can check my resolution also here and you'd see that it's NOT like on your image you sent me    http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php

Comment: Ah right, you're referring to the actual screen resolution rather than the borwser viewport. In this case I'll say you cannot cater for every single screen resolution in the world when it comes to a fullscreen background image, but you can add in some media queries to adjust the `background-position` from `center center` to something that work on that resolution. Bare in mind that the viewport on the test you sent is smaller as the browser has additional toolbars.

Comment: You think I know what "browser viewport" means? I only wanted my bg image to look the same on all resolutions. If it's not possible, then I'll go back to how it was originally OR maybe use some other way if there's one.

Comment: This is the viewport: http://www.adopsengineer.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Viewport__adopsengineer_com.png ...As I said before, you cannot always cater for every screen resolution in the world, but you can add in media queries for the main ones. Please do some research on media queries if you're unsure what they are

Comment: You said that I can't cater for every single screen resolution. But the fact is that after I put the code into custom.css, then the bg image DOES look the same everywhere. It's just the scrolling thing that appeared, all of a sudden...